# Why does AddVectoredExceptionHandler crash my DLL?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, dll, exception

I tried adding vectored exception handling to my Win32 DLL, but the call to `AddVectoredExceptionHandler` never returns.  I just get the unhelpful `<app name>.exe has stopped working` dialog.  However, if I debug the dll with the Visual C++ debugger, then it does work, and the handler function gets called at the appropriate time, and all is well.

To be explicit, I'm adding the handler when my DLL is initialized, like so

```
OutputDebugString("before adding\n");
AddVectoredExceptionHandler( 1, VectoredExcepHandler );
OutputDebugString("after adding\n");
```

and when not run through a debugger, DebugView shows "before adding" and not "after adding".

The handler itself looks like the following:

```
static LONG CALLBACK VectoredExcepHandler( PEXCEPTION_POINTERS exInfo )
{
    OutputDebugString("reached handler\n");
    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
}
```

Oh, I'm running Vista Home 64 if that matters.

Event Viewer shows that the error is an access violation in kernel32.dll.

---

Further discoveries that pretty much solve the problem:  I found that if I commented out the `OutputDebugString` call in the handler, the error went away.  So I guess there's some exception that is incompatible with `OutputDebugString`.  And apparently it's not one of the common ones that I might want to examine, like access violation and invalid instruction, because if I check for those exception codes before calling `OutputDebugString`, all is well.

Comment: Is there a possibility that your dll could in fact have been unloaded when an exception occurs? Note that DebugView is not 100 percent reliable - OutputDebugString calls can get lost.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: The .exe never tries to unload the .dll, and the problem with `AddVectoredExceptionHandler` happens even if there is no exception.

Comment: I know it works fine on Vista x64, I've used it.  At least show us a call stack.  Attach the debugger with Tools + Attach to Process.  Assume an environmental problem.

Comment: @HansPassant, If you mean Attach to Process after the "stopped working" dialog has appeared, nothing ever appears in the Call Stack window.  And if I click the Debug button in the dialog, the only debugger it offers is Visual Studio 2010, which I don't have a license for, rather than Visual Studio 2010 Express which I use.  But I'll edit the question to show more information I've discovered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`OutputDebugString` raises an exception whenever it is called. So your exception handler is causing an infinite recursion by calling it, and this causes a stack overflow. See [here](https://maximumcrack.wordpress.com/2009/06/22/outputdebugstring-awesomeness/) for further details.

> Internally, a debug string is handled as an exception. OutputDebugString calls RaiseException with DBG_PRINTEXCEPTION_C (defined as 0x40010006) and the string address and size as the exception parameters.